# JQuery transition from X,Y to X,Y positions

Tags: jquery

I have some div which start from X,Y coordinates to new X,Y coordinates. 
Actually I use .css() to set the new coordinates but I want to add a transitional effect.

Anyone have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#your-element').animate({ top: '20px', left: '50px' }, 1000);
```

Comment: Excellent, I didnt thought It wa so easy with animate !

Answer (score 1):

You can use animate method of jquery. You have documentation and examples here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/